# sql plus searching in different table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this two table. What i'm trying to do is to find out the position number, title, and total number of application.

```
 CREATE TABLE   POSITION (
posNum          varchar2(10)    not null,
posTitle        varchar2(70),
posOfferedBy        varchar2(70),
);

CREATE TABLE    APPLICATION (
appcnPosNum     varchar2(10)    not null
);
```

When i excute this, it display number of application of all position. Even for those positions that have no application, the count display will still show as 1. Please guide me along. Thanks. I'm using oracle database 11g

```
SELECT posNum, posTitle,count(*)
FROM position 
FULL OUTER JOIN application on position.posNum = application.appcnPosNum
GROUP BY posNum, posTitle;
```

Comment: you need to use `count(application.appcnPosNum)` or count distinct application.appcnPosNum)` if there can be duplicate values in the table application.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from application;
APPCNPOSNU
----------
1
2
25
1

select * from position;

POSNUM     POSTITLE   POSOFFERED
---------- ---------- ----------
1          title1     pos1
2          title2     pos2
1          title1     pos3
3          title3     pos4
```

The full outer join will take all rows from both tables
A distinct should be ok except if you have duplicates in the application table and if you have applications without positions

```
SELECT posNum, posTitle,count(distinct application.appcnPosNum) ct
FROM position 
FULL OUTER JOIN application on position.posNum = application.appcnPosNum
GROUP BY posNum, posTitle;

POSNUM     POSTITLE           CT
---------- ---------- ----------
null       null                1
3          title3              0
1          title1              1
2          title2              1
```

I prefer to do a left join which retrieves all the positions (rows from left table) and replace by null all the applications not found in the second. All depends on the constraints between those two tables.

```
SELECT posNum, posTitle,count(appcnPosNum)
FROM position 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select distinct appcnPosNum from application )app 
on position.posNum= app.appcnPosNum
GROUP BY posNum, posTitle;

POSNUM     POSTITLE   COUNT(APPCNPOSNUM)
---------- ---------- ------------------
3          title3                      0
1          title1                      2
2          title2                      1
```